# Codeigniter ajax post csrf The action you have requested is not allowed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have the ajax request for fetching the information if user is still logged in or not let's say checking its session, and also i have enabled the  `csrf protection` also and the  `GET` is working fine in all aspects but the problem is only with  `POST from ajax`, i have also turned off the  `re-generation of token` and also did pass the new token to every ajax request, but still it gives me an error :

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

fetching token :

```
var getToekn = function(){
 return $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content');
}
```

call to userLog every 1 minute:

```
var userLog = function () {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('csrf_',getToken);
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + 'action=userCheck',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:formdata,
        processData:false,
        success: function (d) {
            if (d.login === 'true') {
                jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content', d.csrf);
                console.log('loggedin: True');
            } else if (d.login === 'false') {
                if (jQuery('#js_login_again').legnth) {
                    popup('js_login_again', 'o');
                    jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content', d.csrf);
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: site_url + '?pop=loginagain',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var popup = $(data).filter('#js_login_again');
                            jQuery('body').append(popup);
                            popup('js_login_again', 'o');
                            loading('h');

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

i did check if the sent token is correct or not and it is a correct token but the ajax post request still results to an error  `The action you have requested is not allowed.`

The thing is i'm already giving the csrf token to ajax request and the token is being also added to the parameters sent to the url, so it's not the case of token , i'm just lost about why it does so.

also did check the $this->input->post('csrf_');  it's empty.

Comment: [check this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=The+action+you+have+requested+is+not+allowed.in+codeinigter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=GrxhVs3QG4mfugSK47LoBw#q=The+action+you+have+requested+is+not+allowed.in+codeigniter)

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju  if that was the only problem , the thing is i'm already giving the csrf token to ajax request and the token is being also added to the parameters sent to the url, so it's not the case of token , i'm just lost about why it does so.

Comment: It is normal for input->post('csrf_') to be empty. CI's security routines strip it from the $_POST array after it has confirmed that it is valid. How are you able to look for it if you have been sent to the error page? That happens as soon as the token fails validation which is early in the page load.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Has anyone found a solution to this ?